# Simpy for production line simulation

Tags: simpy

I have a number of stations, each stations will be located a machine  and need a worker to operate some operations and produce items, operations are precedent:
example: Stations:

- A[ Operation1[Worker1] ]
- B[ Operation3[Worker1, Worker2] ]
- C[ Operation4[Worker2] ]
  Worker can jump between some stations to operate and produce production, the rule is Create 3 outputs of the first operation then move to the second one.
  And an item must finish the Operation1 then go to Operation2 then go to Operation3
  Each operation needs a certain amount of time to finish. Operation1,2,3 needs 3,1,2 mins in order.

I want to simulate the way to produce 100 pcs.

Example to solve the problem

Comment: does every process need to produce 3 outputs?
Does B need both worker1 and worker2 or just one worker of either type?
Have you tried to write any code?  There is a production line example in the docs to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with processes

```
"""
Quick demo of a production line where:
first station produces 3 entites a a time using 1 resoure type A
second station needs both a resource typa A and a resource type B
third station using a resource type B

set it up so the number of each station can be changed.

programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

# wrap the station processes in a class to bundle resources

class Prod():
    """
    simple class to model a entity/product
    has a unique id for tracking
    """

    next_id = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.__class__.next_id

        self.__class__.next_id += 1

class Station_1_Process():
    """
    Station 1

    producess the entites in 3 at a time
    """

    def __init__(self, env, res_pool_a, next_station):
        """
        cache the env, and resource pool
        """
        self.env = env
        self.res_pool_a = res_pool_a
        self.next_station = next_station

        # start the process that creates products
        self.env.process(self.station_process())

    def station_process(self):
        """
        since this process creates entites and 
        does not wait for entites to show up
        it runs in a infinate loop,
        but it does sieze and release the resource
        so it can be shared with other stations
        """

        while True:
            with self.res_pool_a.request() as req_a:

                # wait for resource
                yield req_a
                print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} Station 1 has resource')

                # make 3 entites
                for i in range(3):
                    # make entity
                    yield self.env.timeout(3)
                    prod = Prod()

                    # send to next station
                    self.env.process(self.next_station.station_process(prod))
                    print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} station 1 has made product {prod.id}')

            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} station 1 has released its resource')

class Station_2_Process():
    """
    Station 2

    needs a two resouces, both a type A and type B
    """

    def __init__(self, env, res_pool_a, res_pool_b, station_2_pool, next_station):
        """
        cache the env, and resource pool
        """
        self.env = env
        self.res_pool_a = res_pool_a
        self.res_pool_b = res_pool_b
        self.next_station = next_station

        # controls how many station 2 are running
        self.sation_2_pool = station_2_pool

    def station_process(self, prod):
        """
        gets both resources and does next step
        """

        # get a station which also queues up the prods waitting for station 2
        with self.sation_2_pool.request() as stat:
            yield stat
            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} station 2 has started processing product {prod.id}')

            # get both resources
            with self.res_pool_a.request() as req_a:
                with self.res_pool_b.request() as req_b:

                    # wait for both resources
                    yield self.env.all_of([req_a, req_b])
                    print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} station 2 has both resources for product {prod.id}')

                    # do process
                    yield self.env.timeout(1)

                    # send to next station
                    self.env.process(self.next_station.station_process(prod))

        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} station 2 has finished product {prod.id}')


class Station_3_Process():
    """
    Station 3

    needs just type B resource
    No next station
    """

    def __init__(self, env, res_pool_b, station_3_pool,):
        """
        cache the env, and resource pool
        """
        self.env = env
        self.res_pool_b = res_pool_b

        # controls how many station 3 are running
        self.sation_3_pool = station_3_pool

    def station_process(self, prod):
        """
        gets both resources and does next step
        """

        # get a station which also queues up prods waitting for station 3
        with self.sation_3_pool.request() as stat:
            yield stat
            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} station 3 has started working on product {prod.id}')

            # get resources 
            with self.res_pool_b.request() as req_b:

                # wait for both resources
                yield req_b
                print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} station 3 has a resource to process product {prod.id}')

                # do process
                yield self.env.timeout(2)

        # done processing, no next station
        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} station 3 has finished product {prod.id}')

# boot up
env = simpy.Environment()

# define each resource type
resource_pool_A = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
resource_pool_B = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

# use resouces to define the number of station 2 and 3, 
# station 1 is a generator and gets defined later
station_2_pool = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
station_3_pool = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

station_3 = Station_3_Process(env, resource_pool_B, station_3_pool)
station_2 = Station_2_Process(env, resource_pool_A, resource_pool_B, station_2_pool, station_3)

# there is no products 'watting' for station 1
# because station 1 is generating the prodeucts.
# use a loop to create each station 1 generater
for i in range(1):
    station_1 = Station_1_Process(env, resource_pool_A, station_2)

env.run(50)
print('done')
```

Comment: thank man, actually i did the code, but it not work as i expect, i need to track every product for each operation. i will post my code

Answer (score 0):

Here my code: code is long so i put it on my drive.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XwbD5RsHNPb2VJ5xorI3mSafuywxEyXFAKz8HvUGUsQ/edit?usp=sharing

My problem is i cant stop an operation when it finish a number of product.
It raise exception:  No scheduled events left but "until" event was not triggered: <Event() object at 0x105e84130> before finishing a mount of item and the final operation

Thank you.

Comment: You are running your model with "env.run(until=factory.end_event)"  which says run until the event is triggered.  The error is just saying you never tiggered the event but the model is otherwise done.  I ran your model with "env.run()" and it finished without error.

Comment: self.factory.end_event.succeed() i trigger it when i reach the target, as i print on the log, no more event happens when not target reach. it mean i did not reach the target at step 14

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: in "while self.produced_items <= self.Num_To_Move_Next_OP:" does self.produced_items start at 0?  If so you are producing 4 items, not 3.

Comment: Yes Michael, Thank you for that,  I updated it my lasted code. But i am not sure why the script stop before i get all expected number of items at the last step.

Comment: I upped the workers from a capacity of 1 to a capacity of 2 and it finished without error.  This suggests you have a worker not being released.  I having a hard time tracing where.

Comment: Thank man, finally, i made it work :) thank you so much. it run without error now :D